# How to keep the form values after submit a form Laravel/Lumen?

Tags: php, html, laravel, lumen

**My code:** (blade.php)

```xml
<form action="{{ url('/findPropriedadeInteressado/2') }}" type="get" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col p-2">
      <select class="form-control search-slt" name="tipoProp" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option name="query5" value="">Qualquer tipos de aluguer</option>
        <option name="query3" value="Quarto">Quarto</option>
        <option name="query4" value="Casa">Casa</option>
      </select>
      <small id="emailHelp" class="p-1 form-text text-muted">Selecionar tipo de aluguer</small>
    </div>
    <div class="col p-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Local" name="query2" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['query2'])) {echo $_POST['query2'];} ?>">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="p-1 form-text text-muted">Escolha uma localidade</small>
    </div>
    <div class="col p-2">
      <select class="form-control search-slt" name="nquartos" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option name="query5" value="">Numero de quartos</option>
        <option name="query3" value="1">1</option>
        <option name="query4" value="2">2</option>
        <option name="query4" value="3">3</option>
        <option name="query4" value="4">4</option>
        <option name="query4" value="5">5</option>
      </select>
      <small id="emailHelp" class="p-1 form-text text-muted">Selecionar o número de quartos</small>
    </div>
    <div class="col p-2">
      <select class="form-control search-slt" name="areaMetros" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option name="query5" value="">Qualquer área</option>
        <option name="query3" value="7">Até 7 m2</option>
        <option name="query4" value="10">Até 10 m2</option>
        <option name="query5" value="20">Até 20</option>
        <option name="query5" value="100">Até 100</option>
        <option name="query5" value="200">Até 200</option>
      </select>
      <small id="emailHelp" class="p-1 form-text text-muted">Selecione o tamanho do seu aluguer</small>
    </div>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <input type="range" min="50" max="2000" value="400" class="slider" id="myRange" name="lprice">
      <p>Value: <span id="priceFilter"></span></p>
      <input type="hidden" id="priceFilter2">
    </div>
    <div class="col p-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="oriSolar1" value="N" class="ckeckJust1">
          <label for="vehicle1"> N</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="oriSolar1" value="S" class="ckeckJust1">
          <label for="vehicle2"> S</label><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="oriSolar1" value="E" class="ckeckJust1">
          <label for="vehicle2"> E</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="oriSolar1" value="O" class="ckeckJust1">
          <label for="vehicle2"> O</label><br>
        </div>
        <small id="emailHelp" class="p-1 form-text text-muted">Selecione a orientação solar que deseja</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col p-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="extra1" value="1">
          <label for="vehicle1"> Internet</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="extra2" value="1">
          <label for="vehicle2"> Limpeza</label><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="restricao1" value="1">
          <label for="vehicle1"> Fumadores</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="restricao2" value="1">
          <label for="vehicle2"> Animais</label><br>
        </div>
        <small id="emailHelp" class="p-1 form-text text-muted">Selecione opções extra</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col p-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="restricao3" value="1">
          <label for="vehicle1"> Masculino</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="restricao4" value="1">
          <label for="vehicle2"> Feminino</label><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="vehicle2"> Fiaxa Etária</label><br>
          <div id="slider-range"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center mt-5 p-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary wrn-btn">Procurar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**My controller:**

```
public function findPropriedade(Request $request, $idUser)
{
    $user = Utilizador::where('IdUser','=',$idUser)->get();
     //$user = Utilizador::where('username','=' ,$username)->where('TipoConta','=' ,'Interessado')->get();
     $dataLike = Likes::where('IdUser',$idUser)->get();
     //$search_data2 = $_GET['query'];
     $search_data1 = $request->input('tipoProp');
     $search_data2 = $request->input('query2');
     $search_data3 = $request->input('areaMetros');
     $search_data4 = $request->input('lprice');
     $search_data5 = $request->input('nquartos');
     $search_data6 = $request->input('oriSolar1');
     $search_data7 = $request->input('extra1');
     $search_data8 = $request->input('extra2');
     $search_data9 = $request->input('restricao1');
     $search_data10 = $request->input('restricao2');
     $search_data11 = $request->input('restricao3');
     $search_data12 = $request->input('restricao4');

     $proprerties = Propriedade::where('Localizacao', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_data2.'%');
     if (!$search_data1 && !$search_data2 && !$search_data3 && !$search_data4){
         $proprerties = Propriedade::where('Localizacao', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_data2.'%');
     }
     //dd($search_data4);
     if ($search_data1){
         $proprerties = Propriedade::where('TipoPropriedade', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_data1.'%');

     }

     if ($search_data2){
         $proprerties = $proprerties->where('Localizacao', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_data2.'%');

     }

     if ($search_data4){
         $proprerties = $proprerties->where('Preco', '<',(int)$search_data4);

     }

     if ($search_data5){
         $proprerties = $proprerties->where('NumeroQuartos',(int)$search_data5);

     }

     if ($search_data6){
         //dd($search_data6);
         $proprerties = $proprerties->where('OrientacaoSolar',$search_data6);

     }

     if ($search_data7){
        //dd($search_data6);
        $proprerties = $proprerties->where('internetAcess',$search_data7);

    }

    if ($search_data8){
        //dd($search_data6);
        $proprerties = $proprerties->where('limpeza',$search_data8);

    }

    if ($search_data9){
        //dd($search_data6);
        $proprerties = $proprerties->where('aceitaFumadores',$search_data9);

    }

    if ($search_data10){
         //dd($search_data6);
         $proprerties = $proprerties->where('aceitaAnimais',$search_data10);

     }

    if ($search_data11){
        //dd($search_data6);
        $proprerties = $proprerties->where('generoMasc',$search_data11);

    }

    if ($search_data12){
        //dd($search_data6);
        $proprerties = $proprerties->where('generoFemin',$search_data12);

    }

     $proprerties = $proprerties->paginate(1)->appends(request()->query());
     //return response()->json($dataLike);
     return view('find_propriedade',compact('proprerties','dataLike','user'));
 }
```

So, basically, I would like to keep all my submitted values in the inputs after submitting or refresh. For example the value on input named "query2" when I submit the form.
I tried this:

> if (isset($_POST['query2'])) {echo $_POST['query2'];}

But didn't work.
Can someone help? Tell me if you had any doubts.

Comment: This might help https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/fill-input-with-controller-values

Comment: Using Laravel forget about `$_POST` or `$_GET` and `echo`